# How to access the single value of an array inside a dictionary? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
var name = [
    "A" : ["Alberto", "Alessandro", "Aurelio", "Andrea"],
    "B" : ["Barbara", "Beatrice", "Benito", "Bugo"],
    "C" : ["Claudio", "Cassandra", "Cristiano", "Camillo"],
    "D" : ["Dario", "Danilo", "Davide", "Desio"]
]
//how to print value "Aurelio"?

var index = name["A"]
print(index[2])
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

> Value of optional type '[String]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[String]'

Why? What is the best practice?

Comment: The best practice is to follow the suggestion of the error message. Add a `?` or a `!` And please read the section [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) in the Language Guide

Answer (score 1):

index[2] is an optional string array,

```
[String]?
```

and needs to be unwrapped. There are multiple ways of doing this, the simplest of which is

```
print(index![2])
```

[Here's](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) some more information on optionals.

Comment: I’ve finally solved it, thank you very much!